# Simulation/modelling of a RFID system (reader, antenna, tag)

Tags: matlab, simulink

The input parameters for the simulations are:

1. Area of environment where the RFID system will be placed i.e. in a rectangular space.
2. Number of antennas.
3. Number of passive tags within the environment

Output:

1. The performance of the RFID system in terms of for a given number of antennas and tags how many tags will be successful in being powered up from the antennas in order for communication to take place.

How do I even begin to model such a system in Simulink, whereby I keep one the input parameters constant and then vary the other two, and then repeat this process for the other two input parameters? I want to determine for a given area how many antennas will I require to adequately power a certain amount of passive tags.

I have decided to first find how many rfid tags I can power using, let's say as the first scenario, 3 antennas will be used. Once this is done my next step would then be to determine if I achieve successful communication between the reader and the tag. If someone can at least give some guidance to the first part, how many tags can I power up using 3 antennas with the tags been located in a fixed position and how do I determine how many tags are powered in Simulink?

Comment: It's likely to be much more complex when you consider the resonant tuning effects, the orientation of antennas, cross-talk, power required by each tag and the distances between each tag and its nearest antenna.

Comment: @Andyaka the orientation won't matter because I will assume a circular polarisation antenna for the reader. I wont be investigating cross-talk at this point, only if I can power the tags. No communication is being investigated. The distance will be varied. The power will be constant. How then do I start modeling this in Simulink?

Comment: I've never used simulink.